# Toggle Switch not working inside AJAX loaded View

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

I am trying to get a jQuery toggle box to render here in my form but I am using ajax to load the form and it doesn't appear to render the layout jQuery Do I need to add jQuery into my partial view

```
<div class="modal fade" id="MyEditUpateModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</a>
                <h3 class="modal-title">AddEdit Employee</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="Id" />
</div>
```

This is how am styling my partial view

```
@model ElectricalSurvey.DAL.Models.CircuitModel
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<div>
    <form id="myForm">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Resitance, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Passed, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address" })
        <select asp-for="CirtcutType"
                asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(ElectricalSurvey.DAL.Models.CircuitModel.CirtcutTypes))"
                class="form-control"></select>

        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">@if (Model.Id > 0) {<span>Update</span> } else {<span>Save</span>} </a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div style="text-align:center;display:none" id="loaderDiv">
        <img src="~/Content/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif" width="150" />
    </div>

</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            $("#loaderDiv").show();

            var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/Electrician/SaveCircuit",
                data: myformdata,
                success: function () {
                    $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                    $("#MyEditUpateModal").modal("hide");
                    window.location.href = "/Electrician/Index";

                }

            })
        })

    })


</script>


<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>

<script src="~/bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
```

The toggle renders but it will not toggle as if it cannot find the jquery at all however their is no errors in the console to say that $ is undefined which is strange.

[image: ed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put your js references in partial view **before this checkbox input control**.

This will make sure to reference the js function before html rendering.

```
@model ElectricalSurvey.DAL.Models.CircuitModel
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-switch/3.3.4/js/bootstrap-switch.js" data-turbolinks-track="true"></script>

<script src="~/bootstrap-toggle/js/bootstrap-toggle.js"></script>
<div>
    <form id="myForm">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Name" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Resitance, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Passed, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Address" })
        <select asp-for="CirtcutType"
                asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList(typeof(ElectricalSurvey.DAL.Models.CircuitModel.CirtcutTypes))"
                class="form-control"></select>

        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked data-toggle="toggle" data-onstyle="success" data-offstyle="danger">
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a href="#" id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">@if (Model.Id > 0) {<span>Update</span> } else {<span>Save</span>} </a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div style="text-align:center;display:none" id="loaderDiv">
        <img src="~/Content/InternetSlowdown_Day.gif" width="150" />
    </div>

</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {

            $("#loaderDiv").show();

            var myformdata = $("#myForm").serialize();

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/Electrician/SaveCircuit",
                data: myformdata,
                success: function () {
                    $("#loaderDiv").hide();
                    $("#MyEditUpateModal").modal("hide");
                    window.location.href = "/Electrician/Index";

                }

            })
        })

    })


</script>
```